# Incrementally finding regular expression matches in streaming data in Python

Tags: python, regex, stream

I have data streaming into a number of TCP sockets continuously. For each, I have a different regular expression that I need to pull out matches for.  For example, one might match numbers of the format ##.# followed by the letter f:

```
r = re.compile(rb'([0-9][0-9]\.[0-9])f')
```

Another might match numbers of the format ### preceded by the letter Q:

```
r = re.compile(rb'Q([0-9][0-9][0-9])')
```

In reality, the expressions may be of arbitrary length and complexity, and are pulled from configuration files and not known in advance. They are not hard-coded.

When new data comes in, I append it to a buffer of type `bytearray()` (here called `self.buffer`). Then I call a function like this (with `self.r` being the compiled regular expression):

```
def advance(self):
    m = self.r.search(self.buffer)

    # No match. Return.
    if m is None:
        return None

    # Match. Advance the buffer and return the matched groups.
    self.buffer = self.buffer[m.end():]
    return m.groups()
```

If there is no match yet, it returns None. If there is a match, it returns the match and discards the buffer up to the end of the match, making itself ready to be called again.

However, this method isn't particularly efficient. The problem is that the buffer has to be scanned from the beginning over and over again--whenever new data comes in--until a match is found.  This could be thousands of times and millions of characters scanned repeatedly, before a match is found and the start of the buffer can be advanced.

I can't simply discard the contents of the buffer before a match is found because a match *might* need the last few bytes of the buffer (or even the entire buffer). Once more data comes in, the end of the buffer could be the start of a match.

How can I rewrite my "advance" function to safely discard portions of the buffer that could never contain the start of the regular expression so the entire buffer needn't be scanned repeatedly?

One possibility: Is there an alternative to "search" that returns something other than "None" if the reason the match wasn't found was because the end of the string was reached? And, if so, can I get the starting position of the potential match? That would allow me to discard the buffer up to that point.

Another possibility: Some type of library that is smart enough to rewrite arbitrary regular expressions so they can match in a different--and detectable--way on truncated strings.

I would entertain other possibilities as well, but they do need to work with arbitrary regular expressions and not just the simple ones above. Ideally, they also wouldn't involve scanning the buffer twice (once to find an actual potential match and once to discard things).

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no good way to apply regexes to streamed data in Python. `re` needs all data in memory at once. You can't even assume you can advance the buffer when you find a match on partial data, because maybe you would have found a *different* match if you had all the data, or maybe it wouldn't even have been a match, if the regex has nasty lookaheads in it. With the `re` API, there's no way to be sure.

Comment: The [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module (3rd-party library, not `re`) has support for partial matches, which solve some of these problems, but I don't think they solve the problem of finding the wrong match, and I don't know how they handle lookarounds.

Comment: If the regex is really that simple, it sounds like you might want to write a simple custom parser..

Comment: @user2357112 That `regex` module is *exactly* what I'm looking for. I'm OK with it finding partial matches because I can document that and users will just have to take that into account when writing their regular expressions. It's no different from the current behavior, but should be considerably more efficient. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Apparently the `regex` module's partial match functionality actually *will* report a partial match when it could report a complete match, if more data could change the match. I think this might actually be a complete solution. Not sure, though - I might be missing some weird edge case.

Comment: @user2357112 I tried it in my code; it seems to be working correctly across all the regex's in my test suite. Plus it was only a matter of adding a few lines of code to handle the "partial" matches. I'd call it perfect, or as near as I can reasonably expect.

Comment: I keep coming up with more things that manual window handling breaks. `regex`'s partial match support is still probably the best option currently available for applying regexes to streams, but you really have to be aware of the sliding window and stay away from all the features it breaks if you're going to use a sliding window over your data.

Comment: @user2357112 Agreed. In general the regular expressions my users will come up with shouldn't be *too* crazy, but even so I'll add a section to the documentation with a few examples of how things might fail so that they understand the implications of the (expanding) sliding window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 3rd-party [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module (not `re`) offers partial match support, which is a partial solution. (Lookbehinds, the `^` anchor, zero-width matches, and the `\b`/`\B` anchors all break in subtle or not-so-subtle ways when you try to discard the start of the window and continue the search. With how many edge cases I've thought of so far, I wouldn't be surprised if there are more.)

If you pass `partial=True` to `regex.match`, `regex.search`, `regex.fullmatch`, or `regex.finditer`, then in addition to reporting ordinary, complete matches, it will also report things that don't match, but could if the string was extended:

```
In [8]: import regex

In [9]: regex.search(r'1234', '', partial=True)
Out[9]: <regex.Match object; span=(0, 0), match='', partial=True>

In [10]: regex.search(r'1234', '12', partial=True)
Out[10]: <regex.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='12', partial=True>

In [11]: regex.search(r'1234', '12 123', partial=True)
Out[11]: <regex.Match object; span=(3, 6), match='123', partial=True>

In [12]: regex.search(r'1234', '1234 123', partial=True)
Out[12]: <regex.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='1234'>
```

You can determine whether a match was partial or complete with the match object's `partial` attribute:

```
In [13]: regex.search(r'1234', '12 123', partial=True).partial
Out[13]: True

In [14]: regex.search(r'1234', '1234 123', partial=True).partial
Out[14]: False
```

It'll report a match as partial if more data might change the match result:

```
In [21]: regex.search(r'.*', 'asdf', partial=True)
Out[21]: <regex.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='asdf', partial=True>

In [22]: regex.search(r'ham(?: and eggs)?', 'ham', partial=True)
Out[22]: <regex.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='ham', partial=True>
```

or if more data might cause a match to not be a match:

```
In [23]: regex.search(r'1(?!234)', '1', partial=True)
Out[23]: <regex.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1', partial=True>

In [24]: regex.search(r'1(?!234)', '13', partial=True)
Out[24]: <regex.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1'>
```

When you reach the end of the data stream, you should turn off `partial` to let `regex` know that this is the end, so partial matches don't hide complete matches.

With partial match information, you can discard everything up to the start of a partial match and know that none of the discarded data would have been in a match... but lookbehinds might need that data, so it'd take messy extra work to support lookbehinds if you're doing this. `^` will also get confused by the start of the string changing, `\b`/`\B` won't know whether there was a word character at the end of the discarded data, and it'd be tricky to get zero-width match behavior correct, for whatever definition of "correct" you choose. I suspect some of the other advanced features `regex` offers might also interact strangely if you discard data this way; `regex` has a lot of features.